# Dell Inspiron webcam only showing us as black and white and grainy/pixalated

Tags: laptop, webcam, camera

Hoping someone can help me.
I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series. THe webcam is not only showing us as black and white, mainly white so you can really tell who is who, really grainy, like when your TV station turned off for the night.

I think I might of moved some files from my C drive to my D drive to make some space, that might of made the issue, but I dont know, as we hadnt used the camera for a few months.

PLs help!

thanksyou

Comment: Moving files got another partition or another drive would absolutely not cause the problem you described

Comment: thank you. At least that is one thing I can cancel out. I thought I might of moved the drivers or something.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently for me, Skype for Business settings were overriding my main cam settings. Check to see if you have skype or skype for business installed. If you do, go to the settings, video device and then reset to defaults.